# Alternative for Nsolve

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization

I have an optimization problem for this 4 bar-linkage.

[image]

Nothing is known(a,b,c,d,x,y) except The Tip of the triangle's co-ordinate which is known for some value of phi (angle between a and d). For Example when phi is 0 Trangle tip is at (1.22,3.66) See the table below.

[image]

The system of equation I ended up with is known as **Freudenstein equation**:

```
φ[ϕ_, a_, b_, c_, d_] := 
 ArcSec[(2 c^2 (d - a Cos[ϕ]) (a^2 + d^2 - 
    2 a d Cos[ϕ]))/(c (d - a Cos[ϕ])^2 (a^2 - b^2 + 
     c^2 + d^2 - 2 a d Cos[ϕ]) - 
  a c √(-(d - 
         a Cos[ϕ])^2 (a^4 + (b - c - d) (b + c - d) (b - c + 
           d) (b + c + d) - 2 a^2 (b^2 + c^2 - 2 d^2) + 
        2 a d (2 (-a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - d^2) Cos[ϕ] + 
           a d Cos[2 ϕ]))) Sin[ϕ])]; 

A[ϕ_, a_] := a {Cos[ϕ], Sin[ϕ]};

B[ϕ_, a_, b_, c_, d_] := {d - c Cos[φ[ϕ, a, b, c, d]], 
c Sin[φ[ϕ, a, b, c, d]]};

λ[ϕ_, a_, b_, c_, d_] := ArcTan @@ (B[ϕ, a, b, c, d] - A[ϕ, a]);

W[ϕ_, a_, b_, c_, d_] := A[ϕ, a] + x {Cos[λ[ϕ, a, b, c, d] + y], 
Sin[λ[ϕ, a, b, c, d] + y]};
```

Should look like this picture if you run the code on Mathematica

[image: Should look like this]

Then I run this code to get 24 equation for the triangle tip co-ordinate(see the 2nd image (phi, x, y table ))

```
System = W[#, a, b, c, d] & /@ {0, π/6, π/3, π/2, (
 2 π)/3, (5 π)/6, π, (7 π)/6, (4 π)/3, (
 3 π)/2, (5 π)/3, (11 π)/6} // Simplify // Flatten
```

The problem is when I am trying to solve this using

> NSolve

```
NSolve[System == {1.22`, 3.66`, 0.9`, 2.7`, 1.2`, 1.93`, 1.93`, 1.48`,
3.1`, 1.46`, 4.58`, 1.85`, 5.8`, 2.36`, 6.12`, 3.2`, 5.62`, 4.06`,
4.57`, 4.8`, 3.24`, 4.9`, 2.04`, 4.45`}, {x, y, a, b, c, d}, Reals]
```

It runs for eternity. Can any one tell me if I have any other option to solve this in Mathematica? Thanks

**Update** The table has changed because I made a mistake, instead of taking phi from 0-360, I took it from 0-180. The table has been changed. so Is the corresponding code(code block 2)

Comment: You can try [`FindRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html) if you know some initial guess.

Comment: `Reduce` is generally the most powerful equation solving function in Mathematica. Be sure to add constraints if you have any. (e.g, all  your variables are positive; that's useful to include in the problem). Short of that: like the above comment says, try `FindRoot` with an initial guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use NMinimize!

Assuming the modelled behavior of your system gives xModel[PHI,para],yModel[PHI,para] with para={x, y, a, b, c, d} then you have to minimize

```
J=Sum[#.#&[ {xModel[PHI,para],yModel[PHI,para]}-{xTable[PHI],yTable[PHI}],{PHI}]
NMinimize[J,para]
```